# add section on recyclerView dynamically on runtime (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i have a RecyclerView which have some values now i want to add 2 sections one for `favourites` another for `defaults` i can do it manually like this :

i have `ChannelsAdapter` for holding the values :

```
public class ChannelsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChannelsAdapter.ChannelsViewHolder> implements Filterable  {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

List<ChannelsInformation> data = Collections.emptyList();

private final List<ChannelsInformation> filteredChannelsList;

private final MultiSelector mMultiSelector = new MultiSelector();

  ArrayList <String> selectedChannelName , selectedChannelID;

private HashMap<String, Boolean> map;


private TabFragment5 tabFragment5;


public ChannelsAdapter(Context context,  List<ChannelsInformation> data){

    inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(context);


    this.context = context;


    this.data = data;


    filteredChannelsList = data;
}

public void remove(int position){
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}


@Override
public ChannelsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_channel_row, parent, false);

    ChannelsViewHolder holder = new ChannelsViewHolder(rowView);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ChannelsViewHolder holder, final int position) {

  final  ChannelsInformation current = data.get(position);

    holder.CHANNELNAME.setText(current.channelName);


    selectedChannelName  =  new ArrayList<String>();
    selectedChannelID =  new ArrayList<String>();

    holder.mSolvedCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if (!selectedChannelID.contains(current.id)) {
                holder.mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(true);
               selectedChannelName.add(current.channelName);
               selectedChannelID.add(current.id);

           } else {
                holder.mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(false);

               selectedChannelName.remove(current.channelName);
               selectedChannelID.remove(current.id);

            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new UserFilter(this ,filteredChannelsList);
}



private static class UserFilter extends Filter {

    private final ChannelsAdapter adapter;

    private final List<ChannelsInformation> originalList;

    private final List<ChannelsInformation> filteredList;

    private UserFilter(ChannelsAdapter adapter, List<ChannelsInformation> originalList) {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<>(originalList);
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(originalList);



        } else {
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();


            for (final ChannelsInformation channel : originalList) {

                if ( (channel.channelName != null && channel.channelName.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern))
                        )

                {
                    filteredList.add(channel);

                }

            }
        }
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        adapter.filteredChannelsList.clear();
        if  ((ArrayList<ChannelsInformation>) results.values != null ) {

            adapter.filteredChannelsList.addAll((ArrayList<ChannelsInformation>) results.values);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } }






class ChannelsViewHolder extends SwappingHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView CHANNELNAME;
    CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;




    public ChannelsViewHolder(View itemView) {


        super(itemView , mMultiSelector);

        mMultiSelector.setSelectable(true);

        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectedChannelCheckBox);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        CHANNELNAME = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ChannelNameTxtView);



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


           Toast.makeText(context, ""+CHANNELNAME.getText() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        tabFragment5 = new TabFragment5();

        tabFragment5.addFavoriteSectionToRecyclerView(); // here am calling this function which is throwing me error 

    }

}}
```

and i have an another adapter for sections `SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter` :

```
public class SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private final Context mContext;
private static final int SECTION_TYPE = 0;

private boolean mValid = true;
private int mSectionResourceId;
private int mTextResourceId;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mBaseAdapter;
private SparseArray<Section> mSections = new SparseArray<Section>();


public SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int sectionResourceId, int textResourceId,
                                          RecyclerView.Adapter baseAdapter) {

    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mSectionResourceId = sectionResourceId;
    mTextResourceId = textResourceId;
    mBaseAdapter = baseAdapter;
    mContext = context;

    mBaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
            notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
            notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
        }
    });
}


public static class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView title;

    public SectionViewHolder(View view,int mTextResourceid) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(mTextResourceid);
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int typeView) {
    if (typeView == SECTION_TYPE) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mSectionResourceId, parent, false);

        return new SectionViewHolder(view,mTextResourceId);
    }else{

        return mBaseAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(parent, typeView -1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder sectionViewHolder, int position) {
    if (isSectionHeaderPosition(position)) {
        ((SectionViewHolder)sectionViewHolder).title.setText(mSections.get(position).title);

    }else{
        mBaseAdapter.onBindViewHolder(sectionViewHolder,sectionedPositionToPosition(position));


    }

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return isSectionHeaderPosition(position)
            ? SECTION_TYPE
            : mBaseAdapter.getItemViewType(sectionedPositionToPosition(position)) +1 ;
}


public static class Section {
    int firstPosition;
    int sectionedPosition;
    CharSequence title;

    public Section(int firstPosition, CharSequence title) {
        this.firstPosition = firstPosition;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public CharSequence getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}


public void setSections(Section[] sections) {
    mSections.clear();

    Arrays.sort(sections, new Comparator<Section>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Section o, Section o1) {
            return (o.firstPosition == o1.firstPosition)
                    ? 0
                    : ((o.firstPosition < o1.firstPosition) ? -1 : 1);
        }
    });

    int offset = 0; // offset positions for the headers we're adding
    for (Section section : sections) {
        section.sectionedPosition = section.firstPosition + offset;
        mSections.append(section.sectionedPosition, section);
        ++offset;
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int positionToSectionedPosition(int position) {
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mSections.size(); i++) {
        if (mSections.valueAt(i).firstPosition > position) {
            break;
        }
        ++offset;
    }
    return position + offset;
}

public int sectionedPositionToPosition(int sectionedPosition) {
    if (isSectionHeaderPosition(sectionedPosition)) {
        return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    }

    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mSections.size(); i++) {
        if (mSections.valueAt(i).sectionedPosition > sectionedPosition) {
            break;
        }
        --offset;
    }
    return sectionedPosition + offset;
}

public boolean isSectionHeaderPosition(int position) {
    return mSections.get(position) != null;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return isSectionHeaderPosition(position)
            ? Integer.MAX_VALUE - mSections.indexOfKey(position)
            : mBaseAdapter.getItemId(sectionedPositionToPosition(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (mValid ? mBaseAdapter.getItemCount() + mSections.size() : 0);
}

}
```

and here is my Fragment where am adding values and sections `TabFragment5` like this :

```
        channelsAdapter = new ChannelsAdapter(getActivity(), getData()); // getting values

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    List<SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section> sections =
            new ArrayList<SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section>();

    //Sections , first section by default 

    sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(0, "All Channels")); 

    //Add your adapter to the sectionAdapter
    SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section[] dummy = new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section[sections.size()];
    SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter mSectionedAdapter = new
            SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.section,R.id.section_text,channelsAdapter);
    mSectionedAdapter.setSections(sections.toArray(dummy));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mSectionedAdapter);
```

// well the above is working fine but this is 50% of what i want to accomplished , i want to add the an `default` section when user haven't set any value to favourite and once the user makes any value favourite  i want to add the second section `Favourites` i don't know how can i do it dynamically on runtime ,  i tried this off course didn't worked i got an error :

```
    public  void addFavoriteSectionToRecyclerView(){


    Toast.makeText(context, "Function Called" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    channelsAdapter = new ChannelsAdapter(getActivity(), getData());

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    List<SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section> sections =
            new ArrayList<SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section>();

    //Sections
    sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(0, "Favorites")); // adding second Section dynamically 
    sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(0, "All Channels"));

    //Add your adapter to the sectionAdapter
    SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section[] dummy = new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section[sections.size()];
    SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter mSectionedAdapter = new
     SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.section,R.id.section_text,channelsAdapter);
    mSectionedAdapter.setSections(sections.toArray(dummy));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mSectionedAdapter);

}
```

my error :

```
03-08 13:50:41.397 4237-4237/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pb.myPackage, PID: 4237
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:211)
    at pb.myPackage.ChannelsAdapter.<init>(ChannelsAdapter.java:52)
    at pb.myPackage.TabFragment5.addFavoriteSectionToRecyclerView(TabFragment5.java:420)
    at pb.myPackage.ChannelsAdapter$ChannelsViewHolder.onClick(ChannelsAdapter.java:236)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4469)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18468)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any idea guys why am getting this error ? if yes then please point out the problem or if my approach for adding this section on runtime is not good enough then please suggest me a better approach,  any help or guidance will be much appreciated and helpful for me , thanks

P.S. for adding this sections i followed this [SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058)

UPDATE:

please see the image for better understanding ,  i have a normal RecyclerView where i putted a `section` named as  `default`  .  now by default  there's only first section which is named as `default` now if user selects any value as favourite i want to add another section named as  `Favourites` and move the selected value to `favourites` section

[image: i want to add values into another section like this]

Comment: can u create an image in paint and post as to what u want - a graphical view. Your q is too long and I couldnt understand

Comment: hey @ik024 thanks for responding man , yeah let me update my question

Comment: hey @ik024 please check my updated question

Comment: where are u calling addFavoriteSectionToRecyclerView method ?

Comment: Check the context in the toast msg and also try giving different integer instead of '0' in following line sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(0, "Favorites"));

Comment: in `channelsAdapter` see there last 5 lines `@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


           Toast.makeText(context, ""+CHANNELNAME.getText() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        tabFragment5 = new TabFragment5();

        tabFragment5.addFavoriteSectionToRecyclerView(); // here am calling this function which is throwing me error 

    }`

Comment: I suggest u change ur code structure new TabFragment5() will create a new fragment.

Comment: Hey @ik024  thanks for helping man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tabFragment5 = new TabFragment5();

tabFragment5.addFavoriteSectionToRecyclerView(); // here am calling this function which is throwing me error
```

If `TabFragment5` is indeed a Fragment, then the above code builds a brand new `TabFragment5` and then calls `addFavoriteSectionToRecyclerView()`.

Reading between the lines, I'm assuming you want to call this method on the current instance of `TabFragment5`, and that you don't want to create a new one.

For that, the simplest approach I can recommend is to use an [`EventBus`](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Create an "Event" class as per the EventBus documention, i.e.:

```
public class AddFavoriteSectionEvent {

    public AddFavoriteSectionEvent();

}
```

Register your Fragment to listen for events:

```
    @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
   EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Add a method to your Fragment to respond to these events:

```
@Subscribe
public void onAddFavoriteEvent(AddFavoriteSectionEvent event){
    addFavoriteSectionToRecyclerView();
}
```

And replace the two lines causing your NPE with:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new AddFavoriteSectionEvent());
```

This should resolve your NPE at least.

Comment: hey man thanks a lot for your answer , i really appreciate your effort ,  i just followed your answer but am getting an error while switching to my Fragment Error: `rg.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class pb.myPackage.TabFragment5 and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
                                                     at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findSubscriberMethods(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:67)
 at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:136)` can you tell me what i did wrong ??

Comment: @remyboys That must be a new thing - try adding `@Subscribe` above the `onAddFavoriteEvent()` method.

Comment: hey man thanks a lot now its working fine :) ,  appreciate you